# How to grab text value using unmarshall

Tags: java, xml, unmarshalling

this is my original xml

```
<Descriptions>
    <description lang='en'> This is English version </description>
    <description lang='fr'> This is French version </description>
</Descriptions>
```

I cannot get Text for each description using

```
Unmarshaller ums = JAXBContext.newInstance(Description.class).createUnmarshaller();
```

My Decription.class is:

```
 import java.io.Serializable;
 import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
 import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
 import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;
 import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
 import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
 @XmlRootElement(name = "description")

 public class description implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    
    private String lang;
    private String text;

    public description() {
        super();
    }
    
    public description(String lang, String text) {
        super();
        this.lang = lang;
        this.text = text;
    }

    
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "description [lang=" + lang + ", text=" + text + "]";
    }
    @XmlElement(name = "lang")
    public String getLang() {
        return lang;
    }
    @XmlElement(name = "text")
    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public void setLang(String lang) {
        this.lang = lang;
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }
```

}

But once I manually change Xml to the following format, text value is grabbed.

```
<Descriptions>
    <description> 
        <lang> en</lang> 
        <text>This is English version </text>
    </description>
    <description> 
        <lang> fr</lang> 
        <text>This is French version </text>
    </description>
</Descriptions>
```

Do you have any solution to grab the text value without changing the original xml format?
Could you let me know your solution, please?

Thanks
Linda

Comment: Hey, Java classes names should start with upper case :)

Answer (score 1):

Your `Description` matches the XML Schema you've changed manually. That's why it works.

you've declared two elements

```java
    //  <lang>..</lang> 
    @XmlElement(name = "lang")
    public String getLang() {
        return lang;
    }

    //<text>..</text>
    @XmlElement(name = "text")
    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }
```

However your actual `<description>` element has one attribute `lang=..` and inner text value, hence you should change your `Description` class as follows.

```java
   //  lang='..'
   @XmlAttribute(name="lang")
   public String getLang() {
       return lang;
   }

   // inner text value e.g 'This is English version'
   @XmlValue
   public String getText() {
       return text;
   }
```